# What do the icons in the FileZilla Server connection list represent?

Tags: filezilla

In FileZilla there are icons to the left of the connection's id, I can't seem to find in the documentation what they represent. I am guessing Active vs Passive connections but I don't know.

[image]

Are my suspicions correct? Also any links to official documentation about it would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

here is proof that I am most defiantly logged in but it shows the "not logged in symbol"
[image]

EDIT2:
I kicked one connection and it reconnected with the other symbol
[image]

Comment: Connected/Disconnected? http://svn.filezilla-project.org/filezilla/FileZilla%20Server/trunk/FileZilla%20Server/source/Interface/UsersListCtrl.cpp?view=co&content-type=text%2Fplain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out, it was a bug.

The icon shows the open symbol when you first open the manager then as it sees connections authenticate it will use the closed symbol for the new connections. I let the FileZilla IRC channel know and they fixed it in the repository.

http://svn.filezilla-project.org/filezilla?view=rev&revision=4068

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about the icons, they follow this logic :

- When the user is connecting, but not yet authenticated the first icon is shown. The condition is that the username is empty.
- When the user is connected and username is set, the second icon above is used.

These are the only two icons that will be displayed in the ID column.

---

### Documentation

The best i could find is in [french](http://www.cyberserveur.net/dotclear2/index.php?post/2005/07/10/358-mise-a-jour-du-tutoriel-filezilla-server).

If you want to look at the source, you can do so [here](http://filezilla.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/filezilla/FileZilla%20Server/).

**EDIT**

As Scott noted there is a bug in the code, where the icon is not set correctly in all situations. The code changing the icon looks like this, and is only active for a change user event (USERCONTROL_CONNOP_CHANGEUSER) :

```
    if (pConnectionData->columnText[COLUMN_USER] == "")
    {
        pConnectionData->itemImages[COLUMN_ID] = 5;
        pConnectionData->columnText[COLUMN_USER] = "(not logged in)";
    }
    else
    {
        pConnectionData->itemImages[COLUMN_ID] = 4;
    }
```

But as there are several other events involved, the icon is not correct everywhere as noted.